# ion-refresh background is black instead of white bug

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to implement the `ion-refresher` (https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/refresher) in order to have a nice view when refreshing the view. But I ran into a strange bug. Actually the refresh animation should be in front of a white screen when pulling down the content. But in my app the screen a black screen appears when pulling down the content. In order to find the error I deleted everything in html, css, ts except the part with the `ion-refresh`. But the bug was still there. I know that this code will not help much with detecting the bug but I wouldn't know which code to post further that could cause this issue. I'm asking if you have any ideas what things could cause such a bug?
The ion-refresh logic actually works fine since I can console.log that the event started and terminated. But the view is somehow erroneous.

I append the html(ne css and ts since I deleted everything in order to catch the error, so its not caused by that) code and a picture of the issue.

HTML

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title color="light">
      Refresher
    </ion-title>

    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
    <ion-content>

    <ion-refresher slot="fixed" (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
      <ion-refresher-content></ion-refresher-content>
    </ion-refresher>


    </ion-content>
```

[image: Black background bug]